# Nginx 301 redirects not working from any spot in the config file

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301, nginx-config

Hi guys can I please get some help setting up a 301 redirect for this site?

I've tried adding a rewrite to the main `server{}` block and nothing at all happens no matter what syntax I use (commented out below), and I've tried creating a new `server{}` block specifically for the redirect and nothing happens there as well

I finally managed to use `rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://url2.com/$1 permanent` to create a redirect in the main `server{}` block but it creates an endless cycle of redirects and breaks the site.

I tried using a ton of stack overflow suggestions but I think there's something wrong with either my syntax or the location of my redirect request or something because none of the tutorials i try gets it working! I think I may not be understanding the syntax of a config file enough to be able to know what's wrong.

any ideas? I feel like i've tried every spot possible to put a redirect request and I can't get it to do what i want!

I need to 301 direct all traffic from url1.com to url2.com

```
server {
    server_name url1.com www.url1.com;

    return 301 https://url2.com$request_uri; #nothing
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://ionlearning.com$request_uri permanent; #also nothing (tried each of these individually AND together hahaha)
}

# another attempt, doesn't work at all
#    server {
#        listen  80 default_server;
#        listen  [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
#
#        return 301 https://url2.com$request_uri;
#    }

server {
    root /var/www/blah/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name url2.com www.url2.com;
#       rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://url2.com/$1 permanent;
#       rewrite https://url1.com https://url2.com permanent;
#       rewrite https://www.url1.com https://url2.com permanent;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }


# managed by Certbot

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/url1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/url1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I'm very confused because I've even used examples directly from the nginx.com tutorial!!! help :(

Comment: Assuming you did a `nginx reload` or `nginx restart` after your changes and `nginx -t` which told you that no config issues exist.

Comment: @ShawnC. yes that's right, i restarted nginx and nginx-t says no errors and conf file test successful

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, that kind of issues comes from the server you assume to respond to the request not even being asked.
You should add some general log to your main config and specific ones to each server { ...} you are trying. Especially an access_log is paramount to debug that sort of nightmare.

Comment: oh shoot so I added error logs and access logs to both the url1 server block and the url2 server block and it looks like the url1 block never even gets hit!! the access log is totally empty for that one. I can't even begin to know how to remedy this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So now that you see that it doesn't reach your specific server, the next step is to find where it does go. Hence the general log to see what request hit nginx overall.
Redirections are cached by browser, so if one thing, empty your browser cache, or it might be foolowing a previous wrong redirection that you tested before